# How to know when async function call is finished (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If I have a function call `callFunc()`, and inside that function there is an async call (like a $http in Angular)... from where I call `callFunc()` is there some way for me to know when the function - including all of the async within it - has finished executing?

Comment: All async functions provide a _callback_ function that is called when the async function is finished.

Comment: Yes, but that callback will only work inside `callFunc()` - I want the function that **calls** `callFunc()` to know.

Comment: if you wrote `callFunc`, rewrite it to accept a callback (or return a promise if you're that way inclined)

Comment: If there are sometimes when I don't actually require a callback, how should I write it?

Comment: test if callback is a function and only call it if it is

Comment: If you don't need a callback then why do you need to know if it's done?

Comment: What do you mean you "don't require a callback"? If you don't need to do anything when the function completes just pass an empty function as callback (or as Jaromanda mentioned, don't call the callback if it's not passed to your function)

Comment: Just `return` the **promise** that `$http` yields back to your caller

Comment: @Tushar `All async functions provide a callback function` - **All**? I can think of a suite of asynch functions in the browser that return a **Promise** instead of providing a callback function

Comment: @JaromandaX Ah, _most of them_

Comment: @JaromandaX: A promise still requires you to pass a callback. Only to the promise object's `when()` method instead of directly. But it's still a callback. ALL async functions requires you to provide a callback EVENTUALLY (unless you're using fibres on node.js - but that's another story)

Comment: but you don't provide a callback to the function itself - call me pedantic, but I call it accurate

Answer (score 0):

Async function won't technically returns an indicator for "Completed" before it completes. If you have the control for the service controller, you can send to client side a response size first and for each data chunk you send to the client side, you can make your own progress bar to see when it will complete. But other than calling the a callback function, there is no easy way to see it is finished or not.

Seriously, what is your use case?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to do, and the asynch function invovled

calling an asynch function that takes an optional callback

```
function callFunc(callback) {
    // this ones easy, provide a callback or not, doesn't matter
    asynchFunction(callback);
}
```

calling an asynch function that requires a callback function

```
function callFunc(callback) {
    // provide a dummy callback if one isn't provided
    callback = callback || function() {}; 
    asynchFunction(callback);
}
```

calling an asynch function and manioulating the results before calling the optionally provided callback

```
function callFunc(callback) {
   function localCallback(param1, param2) {
       var manipulateParams = param1 + param2;
       if(typeof callback == 'function') {
           callback(manipulateParams );
       }
   }
   asynchFunction(localCallback);
}
```

alternative: using promises

in the case of $http

```
function callFunc() {
    return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'url'
    });
}
```

In the case of a function that doesn't return a promise, lets say it uses the "node" convention

```
function callFunc() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    somefunc(param, function(err, result) {
        if(err) {
            deferred.reject(err);
        }
        else {
            deferred.resolve(result);
        }
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

In both cases, you can use callFunc like so

```
callFunc().then(function(res) {
    console.log('success', res);
}, function(res) {
    console.log('error', res);
});
```

Without specific details from you, that's the best I can offer

Answer (score 0):

You can use promise in angular.

```
function callFunc() {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/someUrl'
  }).then(function successCallback(response) {
    deferred.resolve('success!');
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    deferred.reject('failed.');
  });
  return deferred.promise;
}

var promise = callFunc();
promise.then(function(res) {
  alert('successCallback: ' + res);
}, function(res) {
  alert('errorCallback: ' + res);
}, function(res) {
  alert('notifyCallback: ' + res);
});
```

Comment: `$http` returns a promise - so, your `callFunc` need not be so verbose or complex

Comment: Yes, I knew. This is just an example for the question.
The $http can be replaced by any func.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a javascript code example of function with a callback.

```
function callFunc( param1, param2, callback ) {

   //your codes of the function 
   //call the callback with some parameters
   window[callback]( param1, param2 );
}
```

Example of calling the function

```
callFunc( 'this is param1', 'this is param2', 'call_this_function' );
```

Example of callback function mentioned in the function call

```
function call_this_function( param1, param2 ) {

    //do something
}
```